# Remove "Add new" button from ActiveAdmin has_many form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, helper, has-many

I have nested resources in active admin edit page, but I would like only to allow admin to edit content of existing resources, not to add new nested resources. My code looks like that:

```
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :author
      f.input :content
      f.has_many :comments do |comment_form|
        comment_form.input :content
        comment_form.input :_destroy, as: :boolean, required: false, label: 'Remove'
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

But it add's "Add new comment" button under inputs. How can I disable it, and leave only f.actions buttons for main form?

Comment: i am facing the same problem... Have you solved it?

Answer (score 16):

Starting from `v0.6.1` you can pass `new_record: false` to hide the "Add new" button

```
f.has_many :comments, new_record: false do |comment_form|
...
end
```

The commit [4b58b8](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/commit/4b58b84a81d40d15cee55bf6c1d441cade5c6b30)